# How to dynamically change suffix to the plugin version depending upon the build variant selected?

Tags: android, maven, plugins, gradle

I am working on versioning an android library. The following are the build types defined:

```
buildTypes {
    debug{
        versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
    }
    dev{
        versionNameSuffix "-RC"
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    //define code for appending the versionname suffix for the plugin
}
// need the versionNameSuffix from the runtime buildvariant selected
version "1.1.0-${versionNameSuffix}"
group 'com.mylib.android-libs'
```

Depending on the build variant selected at runtime, the name of the artifact in maven repository folders and files need to append the corresponding versionNameSuffix defined above resulting in the following structure in the repository while publishing.

```
mylibrary
 |_ 1.1.0
     |__mylibrary-1.1.0-sources.jar
     |__mylibrary-1.1.0.aar
     |__mylibrary-1.1.0.pom
 |_ 1.1.0-DEBUG
     |__mylibrary-1.1.0-DEBUG-sources.jar
     |__mylibrary-1.1.0-DEBUG.aar
     |__mylibrary-1.1.0-DEBUG.pom
 |_ 1.1.0-RC
     |__mylibrary-1.1.0-RC-sources.jar
     |__mylibrary-1.1.0-RC.aar
     |__mylibrary-1.1.0-RC.pom
```

Here is the artifactory block:

```
artifactory {
contextUrl = "${artifactoryUrl}"
publish {
    repository {
        repoKey = 'maven-local'
        username = "${user}"
        password = "${password}"
        maven = true
    }
    defaults {
        publishConfigs('archives', 'published')
        properties = ['build.status': "$it.project.status".toString()]
        publishPom = true //Publish generated POM files to Artifactory (true by default)
        publishIvy = false //Publish generated Ivy descriptor files to Artifactory (true by default)
    }
}
resolve {
    repository {
        repoKey = 'repo'
        username = "${user}"
        password = "${password}"
        maven = true
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Does using variant name itself instead of a custom string work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your edit changes your question entirely! Here's my new answer:

First, you need to add `publishNonDefault true` to your `android` section:

```
android {
    ...
    publishNonDefault true
    ...
}
```

Then modify your uploadArchives section to upload multiple archives from the project, using addFilter. [See section 31.6.4.1 here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html).

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://${System.properties['user.home']}/.m2/repository")

            // addfilter for multiple pom upload
            addFilter('debug') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.attributes.classifier.equals("debug")
            }
            addFilter('dev') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.attributes.classifier.equals("dev")
            }
            addFilter('release') { artifact, file ->
                artifact.attributes.classifier.equals("release")
            }

            pom('debug').version = project.version + "-DEBUG"
            pom('dev').version = project.version + "-RC"
            pom('release').version = project.version
        }
    }
}
```

running uploadArchives results in:

```
├───1.1.0                                          
│       mylibrary-1.1.0-release.aar                
│       mylibrary-1.1.0-release.aar.md5            
│       mylibrary-1.1.0-release.aar.sha1           
│       mylibrary-1.1.0.pom                        
│       mylibrary-1.1.0.pom.md5                    
│       mylibrary-1.1.0.pom.sha1                   
│                                                  
├───1.1.0-DEBUG                                    
│       mylibrary-1.1.0-DEBUG-debug.aar            
│       mylibrary-1.1.0-DEBUG-debug.aar.md5        
│       mylibrary-1.1.0-DEBUG-debug.aar.sha1       
│       mylibrary-1.1.0-DEBUG.pom                  
│       mylibrary-1.1.0-DEBUG.pom.md5              
│       mylibrary-1.1.0-DEBUG.pom.sha1             
│                                                  
└───1.1.0-RC                                       
        mylibrary-1.1.0-RC-dev.aar                 
        mylibrary-1.1.0-RC-dev.aar.md5             
        mylibrary-1.1.0-RC-dev.aar.sha1            
        mylibrary-1.1.0-RC.pom                     
        mylibrary-1.1.0-RC.pom.md5                 
        mylibrary-1.1.0-RC.pom.sha1
```

`repository` can be any maven repo. I have not tested with Artifactory upload, but I understand artifactory should pick up config from maven plugin configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I think I was trying the wrong thing. I need to pull the buildvariant during runtime, and find the appropriate version name suffix and put it in the following: 
`version "1.1.0-${versionNameSuffix}"
group 'com.mylib.android-libs' `

Comment: Can you show how you're publishing to your maven repo?

Comment: Added the artifactory block to the question.

Comment: Also need to see how you're defining publications 'archives' and 'published'. Are you using maven plugin or maven-publish?

Comment: Using 'android-maven' plugin.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am new to this project as well as Gradle.